# D3: Absolute Positioned Tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart in D3 with an absolute-positioned tooltip following the mouse.

Here's the relevant code:

```
.c-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}

chartBar
  .on("mouseenter", (d, i) => {
    tooltip
      .style("left", event.pageX + "px")
      .style("top", event.pageY-15 + "px");
  })
  .on("mousemove", (d, i) => { 
    tooltip
      .style("left", event.pageX + "px")
      .style("top", event.pageY-15 + "px");
  })
```

This works well most cases but it doesn't if I want to add the chart to a relatively positioned element on the page. Because the "left" and "top" of the tooltip will be set relative to that element. 
I tested layerX/Y instead of pageX/Y but that's not widely supported. How can I create a tooltip that is correctly positioned no matter the position of the parent element?

Answer (score 0):

I normally provide a function as the second parameter to the `style` method calls for `left` and `top`, and return different positions based on different criteria.

I normally set `left` based on the x-scale of my graph, then try to add constraints in a `Math.min` function to prevent the tooltip from leaving the graph container. I normally set `top` based on my y-scale.

It could be something like:

```
chartBar
  .on("mouseenter", (d, i) => {
    tooltip
      .style("left", () => {
        return Math.min(
          xScale(d.month) + (x.bandwidth()),
          parseInt(d3.select('.my-graph-container').style('width')) -
          parseInt(d3.select('.d3-tooltip').style('width'))
        ) + 'px';
     })
     .style("top", () => {
       return y(d.amount) + 'px';
    };
  });
```

I remember [this article](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html) being really helpful on creating tooltips that move along with your mouse when it enters a graph.